# "" on $1, why does bash behave like this?

Tags: bash

if a script has

```
if [ $1 == "-?" ]; then #line 4
    echo "usage: ...."
fi
```

when the script get runs without any parameter, it will complain that

```
./script.sh: line 4: [: ==: unary operator expected
```

but if instead

```
if [ "$1" == "-?" ]; then #line 4
    echo "usage: ...."
fi
```

then everything's fine

why is that?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the first argument is missing or empty, your first script evaluates to:

```
if [ == "-?" ] ; then
```

... which is a syntax error. As you noticed, to prevent that you need to make use of `""`, then it evaluates to:

```
if [ "" == "-?" ] ; then
```

AFAIK this is due to the way the original Bourne shell was working. You should make it a habit of enclosing variables in `""` to also work correctly with arguments that have spaces in it. For example, if you would call your script like this:

```
./myScript "first argument has spaces"
```

Then your first script would evaluate to:

```
if [ first argument has spaces == "-?" ] ; then
```

which is also a syntax error. Also things like `rm $1` will not do what you want if you pass filenames with spaces. Do `rm "$1"` instead.

Answer (score 5):

Because `[` replaces the values before executing. `[[` doesn't, so will work as expected.